# How to delete item from Hashmap inside a RefCell within an RwLock-ed Struct

Tags: collections, rust, mutable, borrowing

I have a struct:

```rust
pub struct CommunityContents {
    pub friends: RefCell<HashMap<FriendID, FriendData>>, 
    pub index: RefCell<HashMap<u64, BTreeMap<FriendID, FriendData>>>, 
    pub authenticated: bool,
    pub age: u64,     
    pub height: u64,
}
```

Which is protected with a RwLock with a parent struct:

```rust
pub struct Community {
    pub community_contents: RwLock<CommunityContents>,
}

pub struct FriendData {
    pointer: Rc<Data>,
}

pub struct Data {
    pub key: Key,
    pub friend_ids: Vec<FriendID>,
}
```

I want to be able to modify the data inside `index`. I have no problems inserting data into index doing `write()` to `CommunityContents` and a `borrow_mut().insert(…)` for the `BtreeMap` inside `index`.

My problem is deleting elements from `BtreeMap`, given `FriendID`. My rough attempt is:

```rust
pub fn delete_family(community: &Self, friend_id: FriendID) {
    //get community contents
    let mut g = community.community_contents.write().expect("Lock is poisoned");
    //get friend from inside friends name of community contents
    let mut friend = g.friends.borrow_mut().get(&friend_id).unwrap().pointer.clone();
    // get id attri
    let mut friend_key = friend.key;
    let mut a = g.index.borrow_mut().get(&friend_key);
    let mut c = a.unwrap();
    c.remove(&friend_id);
}
```

And I get the error cannot borrow as mutable. I've tried various things which has made my code above a bit messy.

Edit: sorry I missed out the `FriendData` and `Data` structs in my question.

Comment: Please provide the exact error. Also consider removing fields and types that are not relevant to the problem, to create a [reprex].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making some guesses about the missing types from your example code, I see two errors:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
  --> src/lib.rs:37:21
   |
37 |         let mut a = g.index.borrow_mut().get(&friend_key);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                 - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                     |
   |                     creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
38 |         let mut c = a.unwrap();
   |                     - borrow later used here
   |
   = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

error[E0596]: cannot borrow `*c` as mutable, as it is behind a `&` reference
  --> src/lib.rs:39:9
   |
38 |         let mut c = a.unwrap();
   |             ----- help: consider changing this to be a mutable reference: `&mut std::collections::BTreeMap<u64, FriendData>`
39 |         c.remove(&friend_key);
   |         ^ `c` is a `&` reference, so the data it refers to cannot be borrowed as mutable
```

The first one can be fixed by following the suggestion - use a new variable to ensure that the temporary value (underlined in the error message) lives long enough:

```
let mut tmp = g.index.borrow_mut();
let mut a = tmp.get(&friend_key);
```

Now the borrowed value, `tmp` lives right to the end of the function, outliving `a` which needs to borrow from it.

The second error and suggestion might be harder to understand. `a` is an `Option<&BTreeMap>` but after unwrapping it you are trying to mutate it, so that reference needs to be mutable. The `Option<&BTreeMap>` comes from the call to `get`, so you need to find a way to get a mutable reference instead. you can do that with a different method, `get_mut`, which will return the `Option<&mut BTreeMap>` that you need:

```
let mut tmp = g.index.borrow_mut();
let mut a = tmp.get_mut(&friend_key);
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense and thanks for the explanation to clarify. One other quick thing if you don't mind, do you think the RwLock on the struct makes the RefCells unnecessary? I wonder if I went overkill there.